# Application not being redrawn after collection changed

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I'm trying to recreate the File Explorer using WPF and MVVM. I got a TreeView and ListBox, both of which work properly, as long as the only thing I do is browse through the folders. As soon as I try copying and pasting files, it doesn't redraw the screen and I need to unselect and reselect the folder to be able to see the updated list of items.

(To clarify, I add extra code because I suspect that my problem is not directly related to the `ObservableCollection`s and maybe it is more related to how I implemented everything.)

The overview of my project is the following:

I represent each folder or file using the viewmodels `FileViewModel` and `FolderViewModel`. The FolderViewModel, which is of more interest, contains two strings, one for the full path and one for the name of the file, as well as an `ObservableCollection` containing the contents of a given folder which is lazy-loaded when the contents are retrieved. Here is the `FolderViewModel`. I omitted everything that is not relevant + the Files `ObservableCollection` and methods that are similar to the `Move`:

```
public class FolderViewModel : FileFolderBaseViewModel
{
    public TrulyObservableCollection<FileFolderBaseViewModel> _folders;

    private ICommand _paste;
    public ICommand PasteClicked
    {
        get => _paste;
        set
        {
            _paste = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public TrulyObservableCollection<FileFolderBaseViewModel> Folders
    {
        get
        {
            if (_folderModel.HasDummy)
            {
                _folders.Clear();
                PopulateFoldersOnDemand();
            }
            return _folders;
        }
        set { _folders = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }
    public override bool IsSelected
    {
        get => _folderModel.IsSelected;
        set
        {
            if (value != _folderModel.IsSelected)
            {
                _folderModel.IsSelected = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
                //Remove contents only if not expanded and not selected
                if (!_folderModel.IsSelected && !_folderModel._isExpanded)
                {
                    if (_folders.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        _folderModel.HasDummy = true;
                        Folders.Clear();
                        Files.Clear();
                        Folders.Add(new FileViewModel(new FileModel("dummy", "dummy")));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public bool IsExpanded
    {
        get => _folderModel._isExpanded;
        set
        {
            if (value != _folderModel._isExpanded)
            {
                _folderModel._isExpanded = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();

                //Remove contents only if not expanded and not selected
                if (!_folderModel._isExpanded && !_folderModel.IsSelected)
                {
                    if (_folders.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        _folders.Clear();
                        _files.Clear();
                        _folderModel.HasDummy = true;
                        Folders.Add(new FileViewModel(new FileModel("dummy", "nopath")));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public FolderViewModel(FolderModel folderModel, TrulyObservableCollection<FileFolderBaseViewModel> contents) : base(folderModel)
    {
        _files = new TrulyObservableCollection<FileFolderBaseViewModel>(contents.OfType<FileViewModel>());
        _folders = new TrulyObservableCollection<FileFolderBaseViewModel>(contents.OfType<FolderViewModel>());

        if (Directory.GetDirectories(_folderModel.FilePath).Any())
        {
            _folderModel.HasDummy = true;
            _folders.Add(new FileViewModel(new FileModel("dummy", "nopath")));
        }

        _paste = new RelayCommand(new Action<object>(HandlePaste));
    }

    private void Move(FileFolderBaseViewModel file)
    {
        try
        {
            if (file is FileViewModel f)
            {
                File.Move(file.FilePath, FilePath + "\\" + file.FileName, true);
            }
            else
            {
                Directory.Move(file.FilePath, FilePath + "\\" + file.FileName);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            return;
        }
    }

    private void HandlePaste(object obj)
    {
        if (ClipBoardItem is not null)
        {
            if (PreviousRightClickAction is RightClickAction.Move)
            {
                if (File.Exists(FilePath + "\\" + ClipBoardItem.FileName))
                {
                    MessageBoxResult retVal = MessageBox.Show("File already exists. Overwrite?", "Warning", MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxImage.Warning);

                    if (retVal != MessageBoxResult.Yes)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }
                Files.Add(ClipBoardItem);
                Move(ClipBoardItem);
            }
            ...
        }
    }

    private void HandleClickListBoxFolder(object obj) => IsSelected = true;

    private void PopulateFoldersOnDemand()
    {
        string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(_folderModel.FilePath);
        FileFolderBaseModel model;

        foreach (string dir in dirs)
        {
            DirectoryInfo inf = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
            model = new FolderModel(inf.Name, inf.FullName);
            _folders.Add(new FolderViewModel((FolderModel)model, new TrulyObservableCollection<FileFolderBaseViewModel>()));
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have the `FileExplorerViewModel` which contains two `ObservableCollection`, one for the `TreeView` folders, and one for the `ListBox` items to be displayed depending on the selected folder in the `TreeView`:

```
public class FileExplorerViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private ICommand _selectedItemChanged;
    public TrulyObservableCollection<FileFolderBaseViewModel> ListViewItems { get; set; }
    public TrulyObservableCollection<FolderViewModel> Folders { get; set; }

    public ICommand ChangeRoot
    {
        get => _changeRoot;
        set {_changeRoot = value;}
    }

    public ICommand SelectedItemChanged
    {
        get => _selectedItemChanged;
        set { _selectedItemChanged = value;}
    }

    public FileFolderBaseViewModel? SelectedItem 
    {
        get => FileFolderBaseModel.SelectedItem;
        set
        {
            if(FileFolderBaseModel.SelectedItem != value)
            {
                FileFolderBaseModel.SelectedItem = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();

                if (FileFolderBaseModel.SelectedItem is FolderViewModel selectedFolder)
                {
                    ListViewItems.Clear();
                    foreach (var item in selectedFolder.Folders)
                    {
                        ListViewItems.Add(item);
                    }
                    foreach (var item in selectedFolder.Files)
                    {
                        ListViewItems.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public FileExplorerViewModel()
    {
        _rootDirectory = "C:";
        ListViewItems = new TrulyObservableCollection<FileFolderBaseViewModel>();
        Folders = new TrulyObservableCollection<FolderViewModel>();

        PopulateFolders();
        _selectedItemChanged = new RelayCommand(new Action<object>(HandleListViewItemChanged));
    }

    private void HandleListViewItemChanged(object obj) => SelectedItem = (FileFolderBaseViewModel)obj;

    private void PopulateFolders()
    {
        string[] directoryPaths = Directory.GetDirectories(RootDirectory);

        foreach (string f in directoryPaths)
        {
            FileAttributes attributes = File.GetAttributes(@f);
            if (attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden) || attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.System))
            {
                continue;
            }
            Folders.Add((FolderViewModel)CreateFolderItem(f));
        }
    }

    private FileFolderBaseViewModel CreateFolderItem(string path)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);

        return 
            new FolderViewModel(
                new FolderModel(dirInfo.Name, path), new TrulyObservableCollection<FileFolderBaseViewModel>());
    }
}
```

I tried implementing a `TrulyObservableCollection` so that a modification of an item in the `TrulyObservableCollection` will trigger a `CollectionChanged` event and the app will be redrawn. Then when I paste an item into a folder, either the item is copied/moved into the object also, or the contents list refetches all files and folders using `Directory.GetFiles` and `Directory.GetDirectories`.

I also tried using a `FileSystemWatcher` that fires a `CollectionChanged` event but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

By using the `FileSystemWatcher` in the `FileExplorerViewModel` and repopulating the `ObservableCollection` I could manage and redraw the app as soon as I move or copy an item into a folder that is open.